# Select value of drowdown list having select2() property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my MVC view I want to select option depending on value I am getting from model. I tried it as follow but it is not selecting value when I add bootstrap select2() function to select tag.

```
<select style="width: 100%;" disabled="disabled" id="PositionId">
    <option value="0">---Select Position---</option>
    <option value="1">1st</option>
    <option value="2">2nd</option>
    <option value="3">3rd</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#PositionId').select2();
    //not working with select2()
    $('#PositionId option[value="@Model.CertificatePositionNo"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    //$('#PositionId').val("@Model.CertificatePositionNo");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the value of your `select` element then trigger the change event:

```
// Cache your element in a variable to allow access later...
$yourSelect = $('#PositionId');

// Initialise...
$yourSelect.select2();

// Update value and trigger 'change' event
$yourSelect.val("@Model.CertificatePositionNo").trigger("change");
```

**DEMO...**

```js
var $yourSelect = $("#PositionId");

$yourSelect.select2();

$yourSelect.val("3").trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>


<select id="PositionId">
  <option value="-1">Please select...</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```